# Android tabs in AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-intent, tabs, android-alertdialog

Can I have tabs in AlertDialog?

I've gone through a lot of online tutorials and they usually place the intent from one activity to another in the tabs. However the alert dialog is all within a single activity.

I want to have two tabs in one alert dialog.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can I have tabs in AlertDialog?

Presumably you can use `TabHost` and `TabWidget` in an `AlertDialog`, using views for the tabs. This sample shows views-as-tabs in an activity: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/WidgetCatalog/Tab In your case, you would use the same sort of layout, but use `LayoutInflater` to create the `View` that you then use with `AlertDialog.Builder` to create the dialog.

> I've gone through a lot of online tutorials and they usually place the intent from one activity to another in the tabs.

Those tutorials are obsolete now IMHO. The whole technique of embedding activities in tabs has been deprecated.

Comment: Yes, your should custom your dialog's view.